# Trying to create a login session helper for my features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a features test here:

/spec/features/admin/user_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature "user admin page" do
  scenerio "abc..." do
    user = create(:user)
    login_with(user.email)
    ..
    ..
  end
end
```

I have this:

/spec/features/support/feature.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include Features::SessionHelpers, type: feature
end
```

/spec/features/support/features/session_helpers.rb

```
module Features
    module SessionHelpers
        def login_with(email, password = "Password123")
            visit session_login_path
            fill_in "login_form[email]", with: email
            fill_in "login_form[password]", with: password
            click_button "Sign In"
        end
    end
end
```

When I run rspec on a feature I get this error:

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `login_with' for #<RSpec::Examp...
```

I have a rails_helper and a spec_helper.rb file.

Comment: Does it work when you remove `, type: feature` from `config.include`? That should help narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're including a helper, you can pass in a hash specifying which type of example groups the helper applies to using the `type` option.

The value of `type` should be one of `:controller`, `:model`, `:feature` or `:view`. In your code, you're passing a variable `feature`. It should be a symbol.

```
config.include Features::SessionHelpers, type: :feature
```

If you try to run the specs, you'll get the same error since you haven't let `Rspec` know that you've added an additional configuration in one of the files. To do that, add the following line in your `rails_helper.rb`

```
require_relative './features/support/feature'
```

Note that you can also add the configuration directly in the pre-baked configurations in `rails_helper`.

This will let rspec run the configuration defined in `feature.rb` but you'll again a get an error which says `NameError: uninitialized constant Features`. If you think a bit, in `feature.rb`, you're trying to include `Features::SessionHelpers` but `feature.rb` can't guess where the module is located. You'll have to tell it to require that module with the following statement

require_relative './features/session_helpers'

Now, if you try to run the specs, hopefully your tests will pass :)